# Best way to parse a JSON to store in SQL database (SQL stored procedure/Python)

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, quickbooks-online

I have a table of overly complex JSON files I'm trying to convert to tabular format to store in a SQL database. I'm pulling the JSONs from the quickbooks online API, and the format is messy to say the least.. (We're talking 7x nested JSONs for some bits of it..

The format resembles the code snippet down below. Currently I am using a bunch of OpenJSON's + Cross applys to dig down to the innermost ColData then work my way up but it looks like some of the ColData's get skipped over doing that.

Are there any better ways,  using either Python (since I pull the JSON initially in Python before sending the JSON to a SQL database to parse) or SQL to convert it to tabular format besides manually trying to use OpenJSON with Cross applys?

The goal is to get all of the ColData's into a SQL table...

Thanks!

```
{
  "Header": {
    "ReportName": "BalanceSheet", 
    "Option": [
      {
        "Name": "AccountingStandard", 
        "Value": "GAAP"
      }, 
      {
        "Name": "NoReportData", 
        "Value": "false"
      }
    ], 
    "DateMacro": "this calendar year-to-date", 
    "ReportBasis": "Accrual", 
    "StartPeriod": "2016-01-01", 
    "Currency": "USD", 
    "EndPeriod": "2016-10-31", 
    "Time": "2016-10-31T09:42:21-07:00", 
    "SummarizeColumnsBy": "Total"
  }, 
  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "ASSETS"
            }, 
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Current Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Bank Accounts"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "35", 
                              "value": "Checking"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "1350.55"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "36", 
                              "value": "Savings"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "800.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "BankAccounts", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Bank Accounts"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "2150.55"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Accounts Receivable"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "84", 
                              "value": "Accounts Receivable (A/R)"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "6383.12"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "AR", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Accounts Receivable"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "6383.12"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Other current assets"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "81", 
                              "value": "Inventory Asset"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "596.25"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "4", 
                              "value": "Undeposited Funds"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "2117.52"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "OtherCurrentAssets", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Other current assets"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "2713.77"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "CurrentAssets", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Current Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "11247.44"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Fixed Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "id": "37", 
                          "value": "Truck"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "38", 
                              "value": "Original Cost"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "13495.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Truck"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "13495.00"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "FixedAssets", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Fixed Assets"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "13495.00"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "Section", 
        "group": "TotalAssets", 
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "TOTAL ASSETS"
            }, 
            {
              "value": "24742.44"
            }
          ]
        }
      }, 
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "LIABILITIES AND EQUITY"
            }, 
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Liabilities"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Current Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Accounts Payable"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "33", 
                                    "value": "Accounts Payable (A/P)"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "1984.17"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "AP", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Accounts Payable"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": "1984.17"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }, 
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Credit Cards"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "41", 
                                    "value": "Mastercard"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "157.72"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "CreditCards", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Credit Cards"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": "157.72"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }, 
                        {
                          "Header": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Other Current Liabilities"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": ""
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "Rows": {
                            "Row": [
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "89", 
                                    "value": "Arizona Dept. of Revenue Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "4.55"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "90", 
                                    "value": "Board of Equalization Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "401.98"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "ColData": [
                                  {
                                    "id": "43", 
                                    "value": "Loan Payable"
                                  }, 
                                  {
                                    "value": "4000.00"
                                  }
                                ], 
                                "type": "Data"
                              }
                            ]
                          }, 
                          "type": "Section", 
                          "group": "OtherCurrentLiabilities", 
                          "Summary": {
                            "ColData": [
                              {
                                "value": "Total Other Current Liabilities"
                              }, 
                              {
                                "value": "4406.53"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "CurrentLiabilities", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Current Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "6548.42"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }, 
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Long-Term Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "id": "44", 
                              "value": "Notes Payable"
                            }, 
                            {
                              "value": "25000.00"
                            }
                          ], 
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    }, 
                    "type": "Section", 
                    "group": "LongTermLiabilities", 
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Long-Term Liabilities"
                        }, 
                        {
                          "value": "25000.00"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "Liabilities", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Liabilities"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "31548.42"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Equity"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "id": "34", 
                        "value": "Opening Balance Equity"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "-9337.50"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "id": "2", 
                        "value": "Retained Earnings"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "91.25"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Net Income"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "value": "2440.27"
                      }
                    ], 
                    "type": "Data", 
                    "group": "NetIncome"
                  }
                ]
              }, 
              "type": "Section", 
              "group": "Equity", 
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Equity"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "value": "-6805.98"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "Section", 
        "group": "TotalLiabilitiesAndEquity", 
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "TOTAL LIABILITIES AND EQUITY"
            }, 
            {
              "value": "24742.44"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "Columns": {
    "Column": [
      {
        "ColType": "Account", 
        "ColTitle": "", 
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey", 
            "Value": "account"
          }
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "ColType": "Money", 
        "ColTitle": "Total", 
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey", 
            "Value": "total"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried to get the ColData (unsuccessfully I might add), I think it might be a little too contrived to do in SQL but I'm not sure if I should continue trying this way or if there's a better way in Python:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max)

SELECT @json = json FROM QboApiRawJSONData WHERE ID = 2

 

--Outer layer of JSON breaks into 3 parts - header, columns, rows
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH
(
    Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
)  as MainLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (MainLayer.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as SecondaryLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (SecondaryLayer.Row) 
WITH
(
Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) As ThirdLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (ThirdLayer.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as FourthLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (FourthLayer.Row) 
WITH
(
Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as FifthLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (FifthLayer.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as SixthLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (SixthLayer.Row) 
WITH
(

Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as SeventhLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (SeventhLayer.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as EighthLayer
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (EighthLayer.Row) 
WITH
(
Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as LayerNine

---Things get funky here
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (LayerNine.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as LayerTen
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (LayerTen.Row) 
WITH
(
Rows nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as LayerEleven
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (LayerEleven.Rows) 
WITH
(
Row nvarchar(max) AS JSON
) as LayerTwelve

--21 items in last col
```

Comment: Is the data fields dynamic, or does it follow a specific pattern? it was a bit hard to tell by looking at the json data alone

Comment: and you're just looking to get all the `ColData` values out?

Comment: I assume you've already tried a recursive function which gets the `ColData` values from the JSON object as mentioned

Comment: Yes, all I care about is the ColDatas- I just updated the code snipped to use the example JSON provided by the QBO link at the end of this comment. I haven't tried anything recursive, just been playing around with SQL's openJSON but thinking that could work - would you have an example of that? https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/balancesheet

Comment: @DaleK Apologies, just added my attemped solution with SQL's OpenJSON - I'm not able to get all of the rows by just cross applying over and over, which is why I considered maybe I should just get all of the ColData's inside python if it would be less tedious.

Answer (score 0):

There is JSON support for sql-server:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I've been trying (OPenJSON specifically, I attached my code attempt at the end) but I don't understand why my cross apply's remove specific rows

Answer (score 0):

There is a JSON storage method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-ver15. Although it will be fairly complex here I recommend storing the JSON data as a Logs table and then following the tutorial above to see if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quickbooks API to get the JSON, then refer to this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

and this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

You can also consider setting something like AWS Lambda or Google Cloud Functions if you need something more automated.